# Flutter: null check operator used on a null value error

Tags: flutter, dart, null, null-check

I'm working on a simple e-commerce app. And I got an error as follows:

**E/flutter (13586): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value**

Can't figure what's causing this error even though I saw similar cases and tried to handle null values in my code:

all_products.dart:

```
...
Widget AllProducts() {
  ...
      WatchBoxBuilder(
  box: Hive.box<Product>('products'),
  builder: (context, box) {
    if (box != null) {
      return ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 10, left: 25, right: 25),
        itemCount: products.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int idx) {
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            child: buildProduct(idx),
          );
        },
      );
    } else return Container();
  },
  ),
  ],
  );
}
...
Widget buildProduct(int idx) {
  return Container(
    height: 250,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.deepPurple[600],
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.deepPurple, blurRadius: 7)],
    ),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      children: [
        Expanded(
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
    child: Image.file(File(product(idx).image), width: 150, height: 150),
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        ),
        ),
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
children: [
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 10),
  child:   Container(
    height: 30,
    child:   Text(
      product(idx).name,
      style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 17.5, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
  ),
),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      child: Text(
  product(idx).description,
  style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 12.5, color: Colors.white),
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
  ),
    ),
],
          ),
    ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
...
```

product_details.dart:

```
...
final picker = ImagePicker();
final titleCtrl = TextEditingController();
final descriptionCtrl = TextEditingController();
final priceCtrl = TextEditingController();
String? image;

Widget ProductDetails() {
  ...
 TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(Icons.title),
                labelText: 'Product\'s name',
              ),
              controller: titleCtrl,
            ),
          ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            icon: Icon(Icons.article_outlined),
            labelText: 'Product\'s specifications',
            hintText: 'Describe the product...'
          ),
          maxLines: null,
          controller: descriptionCtrl,
        ),
          ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
          labelText: 'Product\'s price',
        ),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        controller: priceCtrl,
      ),
    ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.deepPurple[300],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
              child: image != null ? Image.file(File(image!)) :
              Center(child: Icon(Icons.image_outlined, size: 30)),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
            child: OutlinedButton(
               child: Text('Pick an image from gallery'),
              onPressed: () async {
                 image = await picker.pickImage(
                     source: ImageSource.gallery).toString();
              },
            ),
          ),
          ...
OutlinedButton(
                  child: Text('Save'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Product product = Product(
                      name: titleCtrl.text != null ? titleCtrl.text : '',
                      description: descriptionCtrl.text != null ?
                      descriptionCtrl.text : '',
                      price: priceCtrl.text != null ? priceCtrl.text : '',
                      image: image != null ? image! : '',
                    );
                    addProduct(product);
                    Get.back();
                   },
  ),
  ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
...
```

Any help will be appreciated :/

**Edit:**

stack trace:

```
E/flutter ( 3030): #0      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:121:86)
E/flutter ( 3030): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:146:36)
E/flutter ( 3030): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
E/flutter ( 3030): #3      MethodChannelPathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsPath (package:path_provider_platform_interface/src/method_channel_path_provider.dart:52:10)
E/flutter ( 3030): #4      getApplicationDocumentsDirectory (package:path_provider/path_provider.dart:115:40)
E/flutter ( 3030): #5      main (package:apple_estore/main.dart:8:30)
E/flutter ( 3030): #6      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:145:25)
E/flutter ( 3030): #7      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1428:13)
E/flutter ( 3030): #8      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter ( 3030): #9      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1863:10)
E/flutter ( 3030): #10     runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1851:12)
E/flutter ( 3030): #11     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:141:5)
E/flutter ( 3030): #12     _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:283:19)
E/flutter ( 3030): #13     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
E/flutter ( 3030):
```

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: Sorry :/, I'm a bit late...

Comment: The stack trace should actually contain the line of the error. Apparently you use the null check operator (!) somewhere on a value that is null, but I couldn't find a place for it in your sample code either.

Comment: maybe your image is null, try print value of your image

Comment: looks like the null value is on line 8 of your main.dart

Answer (score 0):

Problem in buildProduct(idx). ListViewBuilder could not get all the values from db (some are null or empty may be). so comment one by one list items and check result. for more please provide buildProduct() code.

Comment: The box('products') don't have any initial items. The user is supposed to add values from product_details.dart. And the box is checked , but I will provide buildProduct() code anyway...

Comment: Actually the problem is ListViewBuilder is getting empty data. So use this method and try: put a space in empty text(default text adding) and put a dummy image from memory when selected image is empty.